# Does the double integral diverge? $\iint_{\Omega} \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy(1 - x^2 - y^2)}} ~ dx dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Does the double integral converge $$\iint_{\Omega}  \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy(1 - x^2 - y^2)}} ~ dx dy$$
I tried using polar coordinate but then half way I realised it was not a good idea so what do I do?

I got $$\iint_{\Omega} \frac{r}{\sqrt{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta) (1-r^2)}}drd\theta = \int \frac1{\sqrt{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}}d\theta \times \int \frac{r}{\sqrt{(1-r^2)}},dr$$

$$\Omega = \left\{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 < 1, x > 0, y > 0 \right\}$$

But I don't know how to continue, I haven't written the bounds yet because I was trying to simplify it.

Comment: what is your $\Omega$?

Comment: Do you know anything about $\Omega$? You typically cannot separate integrals as you did in your last step.

Comment: Sorry guys I forgot to post the most "important" thing, I have edited it now.

Comment: "I tried using polar coordinate but then half way I realised it was not a good idea" Don't sell yourself short, it was a good idea: in fact, it was probably a compulsory idea.

Answer (score 2):

Integral on the radial part
$$\int_0^1 \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}dr=1$$
Integral on the angle part
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac1{\sqrt{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}} d\theta &=\frac12\cdot2\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{-\frac12}(\theta)\cos^{-\frac12}(\theta) d\theta\\
\\
&=\frac12\cdot B\left(\frac14,\frac14\right)=\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac14\right)}{2\sqrt\pi}\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\boxed{\iint_{\Omega}  \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy(1 - x^2 - y^2)}} ~ dx  dy=\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac14\right)}{2\sqrt\pi}~}$$

Comment: I don't understand the last part. What is B and how did you get $$ \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{-\frac12}(\theta)\cos^{-\frac12}(\theta) d\theta\\ = \frac12\cdot B\left(\frac14,\frac14\right)=\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac14\right)}{2\sqrt\pi}$$

Comment: @Need_MathHelp $B$ is beta function. See eq.(14) and eq.(17) here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html

Comment: @Need_MathHelp If the goal is to discuss convergence we can avoid beta function simply noting that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos \theta\sin \theta}} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{ \theta}}$

Answer (score 0):

As noticed, by polar coordinates we obtain

$$\iint_{\Omega}  \sqrt{\frac{x^2 + y^2}{xy(1 - x^2 - y^2)}}  dx  dy= \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos \theta\sin \theta}}\int_0^1 \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} \;dr \;d\theta  $$

and since $\int_0^1 \frac{r}{\sqrt{1-r^2}} \;dr=1$ all boils down with

$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos \theta\sin \theta}}\;d\theta=2\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos \theta\sin \theta}}\;d\theta$$

and since for $\theta \to 0^+$ we have that $\cos \theta\sin \theta=\theta+O(\theta^3)$ the integral converges by limit comparison test with

$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\theta}}\;d\theta=\sqrt \pi$$

Comment: How do I know that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)}}$~$\frac1{\sqrt{\theta}}$

Comment: @Need_MathHelp As $\theta \to 0^+$ we have $\cos \theta = 1+O(\theta^2)$ and $\sin \theta = \theta+O(\theta^3)$ therefore $\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)=\theta+O(\theta^3)$. As an alternative $\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)=\frac12\sin(2\theta)=\theta+O(\theta^3)$.

Comment: what about when $\theta \to \frac{\pi}2$ ?

Comment: It’s the same argument for symmetry, we don’t need to explore that, but it is almost the same thing.